# How to get the table which is inside a TD of another Table via XPath

Tags: java, html, xpath, htmlunit

I am new to HTML Unit and XPath. I am not sure of the XPath I need to use to extract the inner table contents inside of a TD of another Table. I have an XML of the following type

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td>
         <table>
           ...
           ... 
         </table> 
     </td> 
   </tr>
  </table>
```

Appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to use XPath to get to the inner table. Then you should apply the same logic to get to the outer table.

If you reached the outer table this way:

```
/path-to-outer-table/table
```

Then, considering the provided HTML code, you reach the inner table this way:

```
/path-to-outer-table/table/tr/td/table
```